# Jackson json parser exception

Tags: java, android, json, data-binding, jackson

I use Jackson 2.2.3 on my latest android Project.
I have included the jars (core, databingin, annotation) as jars to my android libs folder.

But i get this error when reading / parsing json. Write json from an objects works.

I call this:

objectMapper.readValue(inputStream, SubscriptionWrapper.class);

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting
>   setter definitions for property "wallpaper":
>   android.content.Context#setWallpaper(1 params) vs
>   android.content.Context#setWallpaper(1 params) at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:272)
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:272)
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:247)
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:146)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findContextualValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:305)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer.findDeserializer(StdDeserializer.java:634)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.resolve(BeanDeserializerBase.java:438)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:298)
>   ... at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2884)
>   at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2034)

My class looks like this

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class SubscriptionWrapper {

    @JsonProperty("device")
    private Device device;

    @JsonProperty("subscriptions")
    private List<Subscription> subscriptions;

    public SubscriptionWrapper() {
    }

    public SubscriptionWrapper(Device device, List<Subscription> subscriptions) {
        this.device = device;
        this.subscriptions = subscriptions;
    }

    public Device getDevice() {
        return device;
    }

    public void setDevice(Device device) {
        this.device = device;
    }

    public List<Subscription> getSubscriptions() {
        return subscriptions;
    }

    public void setSubscriptions(List<Subscription> subscriptions) {
        this.subscriptions = subscriptions;
    }

}
```

Any idea what could be wrong? I have used jackson in other projects without any issues.

Comment: also, what is a subscription, what is a device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damn, I found the solution:

my Device class has a method

```
public void setStatistics(Context c);
```

that will be called to fulfill statistics about the users device.

The method is called from jackson, even if in the json that should be parsed do not contains a "statistics" element.
Annotating the method with `@JsonIgnore` has solved the problem.

```
@JsonIgnore
public void setStatistics(Context c)
```

So I have to annotated every single method or configure jackson to use field instead of methods for pasing as default.

Comment: I experienced this issue as well, but only on a samsung S3 (4.4).

I had a Resources member in one of my data classes. I had to use the `@JSONIgnore` on this member for things to work. 

`@JsonIgnore
private Resources resources;`